# C2DM error: Got error response from Google datamessaging endpoint: MismatchSenderId

Tags: android, android-c2dm

Hi am creating an application that use C2DM services. the following steps i followed
1)Registered my package name and roll email id. 2)created an activity to receive the registration_Id. 3)created an activity to send the data to C2DM cloud.
My prob is i was able to receive registration_id,SID,LSID,Auth. When i try to send data(message) to C2DM, i get HTTP Response as 200(i.e connection Success, but check for errors in the body) but i get an error which is as below:

`W/C2DM(381): Got error response from Google datamessaging endpoint: MismatchSenderId`.

what should be done next,pls suggest.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please help awaiting ur earliest  response

Answer (score 1):

Double check that the Email argument you used to get the Google Client Auth token is the same as the sender ID you used when registering for C2DM on the Android client.

Double check that you are using only the Auth value (without "Auth=" prefix, without trailing newline, etc.) when posting to C2DM servers.

Can you test sending a notification from outside of the Android app, e.g. using cURL on the command-line?

Comment: i have crossed checked.its correct. Dont know where am going wrong